# D3 - path outputs 0px by 0px - map won't show up - not sure how to use projection for this

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am trying to make a world map in D3.  I received the JSON file from this link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json

Below is my code.

```
  // Define SVG size
  var width = 800;
  var height = 500;

  // Define SVG attributes
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

  d3.json("/map.json", function(error, map) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);

    console.log(map);

    svg.append("g")
    .data(map.features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr("class", function (d) {
      return d.properties.name;
    })
    .attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));

  });
```

When I run it on my localhost, below is what appears per country so I know it is correctly reading the json file:

path class="Angola" d="M522.7427503528568,  -- etc.

I have tried playing with different projections to get the map to show, but I haven't been able to figure it out.  The path for each country displays 0px by 0px.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1.) In order to bind data you need a [selector](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data):

```
svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".country") // <- selector
    .data(map.features)
    .enter().append('path')
    .attr("class", "country") // <- giving all paths the same class
    .attr('d', d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
```

2.) You need to add a little bit of style:

```
.country {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
}
```

You should also note that in the data you link to there's [something wrong with bermuda](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/issues/10).

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ys3Cd0hbVuXX0z5dKDXE?p=preview).

Comment: Wow! This worked. Thanks so much and for taking the time to help out. I've been racking my head at this for the entire day.